# How to add calendar events to everyone's calendar?

Tags: exchange-2010, calendar, share

I currently work at a University and we have a request to add our campus holidays and academic calendar to everyone's individual calendars. This way the holidays will show up by default on everyone's calendar. We also would like these events NOT to block off that day and prevent scheduling.

Is this possible? Would a shared calendar be a better solution than importing events? (If it is possible, how would one go about doing this task.)

I can provide more information if this was unclear. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you considered, or stated that this is far from the best approach to this problem?  Most large organizations maintian a calendar for organizational events for a reason, namely that it's a better tool for handling this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a shared calendar for holidays but there is no way to add it to every user's individual calendar unless you take advantage of Exchange Web Services. There are a couple articles about this

http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to.html and http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to_22.html